# Livewire and Eloquent - Sums of multiple columns in filtered collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

quite a noob in Laravel and Livewire, I guess if there is a better way to accomplish what I have here:

I have some checkboxes in a Livewire view that allow the user to dynamically choose how to filter the data being shown in a HTML table.
On the controller I have an eloquent query that retrieves a subset of the records in the db whenever a checkbox changes state.
Like this (I tried to simplify the structure):

```
$filtered_items = Item::select('item_color', 'item_quantity', 'item_value')
        ->whereIn('item_color', [ /* array controlled by checkboxes values in view */ ])
        ->get();
```

I need to also show the sums of some columns for that specific filter setup.
As I don't want to make new queries, I try to work on the already available collection with a `->sum()` for each column I want to sum:

```
$sums['item_quantity'] = $filtered_items->sum('item_quantity');
$sums['item_value'] = $filtered_items->sum('item_value');
```

It works as intended, as I have an array with the sums, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this, or even write a function to get more columns sum at once, maybe passing an array.

Thanks for any idea or link!

Comment: Do you need the items/item_colors returned by your query or just the sums ?

Comment: Ideally an array with column names as keys and sum of then whole column as values

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a single query for all sums (two in this example)

```
$filtered_items = \DB::table('items')
        ->selectRaw('SUM(item_quantity) as sum_quantity, SUM(item_value) as sum_value')
        ->whereIn('item_color', [ /* array controlled by checkboxes values in view */ ])
        ->first();
```

The advantage is that it will return one entry/row instead of a collection of all the items which is way faster.

Comment: N69S I see your answer and I think I did not explain correctly. I still need all the filtered items details, as for my first query. Running this second query after the first one is faster than working on the already retrieved collection?